# Detailed error report for every object in the scene

Tags: rendering, command-line, error

I am rendering via Win7 command line and each frame I get message like **cycle dependencies**, **shrinkwrap out of memory**, **can't create particles with current modifier stack**... without mentioning actual objects.

This reports are quite vague. As I have *lots of objects* that are using shrinkwrap and particles, I do not want to go through every object manually.

Can I get more specific info?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to make Cycles more verbose to print the name of the object which causes this problem.

The error message indicates *shrinkwrap out of memory* : only objects with a *Shrinkwrap* modifier should cause this error. This can help you to reduce the number of objects to analyze.

You can use the Outliner to quickly enable or disable the render of an object (with the Eye button at the right of the object name). With a dichotomy method, you should find quickly the wrong object :

In a first pass, disable the render of the alf of the objects with a Shrinkwrap modifier and try a render. If the error disapears, the wrong object is in the alf you just disabled. Otherwise, it's in the second alf.

In a second pass, keep disable the render of objects witch do not cause the error, and disable the alf of the remaining objects. With a new render, you will see if the error disappears or not.

After few iterations, you should find quickly the wrong object.